# Changing ''pricelevelid'' field based on another field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, field

im so new to javascript, my situation is beginner of the beginner :)
But i have to write a code on mscrm 2011 order entity.

i have two field, pricelevelid and new_taxincl(radio button). I want to change value in pricelevelid field based on selection of new_taxincl field.
If user select ''yes'' i want to fill pricelevelid field with ''USD -Tax Included-'', ''no'' ''USD -without tax-''. This have to run onChange event.

I could not write the correct code so far.

Any help will be fine for me.
Thanks.

PS: new_vrg is a field in the pricelevel entity and has same value with new_taxincl field in the order entity.

here is my code:

```
    function callRetrievePList() {
    var field = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_taxincl");
    if ((field == null) || (field.getValue() == null) || (field.getValue()[0] == null) || (field.getValue()[0].id == null))
        return;

    var plistfield = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("pricelevelid");
    if (plistfield != null && plistfield.getValue() != null)
        return;
    var options = "$select=PriceLevelId,Name&$filter=new_vrg/Id eq (guid'" + (field.getValue()[0]).id + "')";
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("PriceLevel", options, retrievePListCallBack, errorCallBack, completeCallBack);

}

    function retrievePListCallBack(retrievedStock) {
    var plistfield = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("pricelevelid");
    if (plistfield != null && plistfield.getValue() != null)
        return;

    for (var i = 0; i < retrievedStock.length; i++) {
        var stock = retrievedStock[i];

        var lookupReference = [];
        lookupReference[0] = {};
        lookupReference[0].id = stock.PriceLevelId;
        lookupReference[0].entityType = "pricelevel";
        lookupReference[0].name = stock.Name;
        plistfield.setValue(lookupReference);

        return;

    }
}

function errorCallBack(errorObject) {
}

function completeCallBack() {
}
```

Comment: +++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code may help you:

To get a radio button in CRM JavaScript:

```
function TaxIncludedRadioButton_OnChange()
{
var taxInclBtn= Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_taxincl").getAttribute().getValue();
var lookup = new Array();
lookup[0] = new Object();
if(taxIncludeRdBtn==true)
{

lookup[0].id = yourrecorid1;
lookup[0].name = 'USD -Tax Included-';
lookup[0].entityType = entityname;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").setValue(lookup);
}
else if(taxIncludeRdBtn==false)
{
lookup[0].id = yourrecorid2;
lookup[0].name = 'USD -Without-tax';
lookup[0].entityType = entityname;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").setValue(lookup);

}
}
```

**Register the above function OnChange event of you new_taxincl radio button**